# sum sign in number cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In 2 cells, I exactly have these values:

```
A1: 1+2+3
A2: 2+0.5+10
```

Is it possible to have sum of these cells (=18.5) in another cell?
I tried `=SUM(A1:A2)`, but it returns `0`

Comment: I guess those cell input are formatted as text?

Comment: @djerry: yes, but changing it to Number didn't have any effects.

Comment: That's because a "=" is needed in front of it to calculate the cells, but that would mean that you lose you "1+2+3" syntax and that it would show "6" instead. Is it required that "1+2+3" stays visible in A1?

Comment: @djerry: yes. May I want to print this sheet, and I should be able to see the values correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This can't be the most efficient use of this method, but it's what I can figure out. Hopefully someone has something better.*

Make sure you have the developer tab in the ribbon. If not, go to `File - Options - Customize Ribbon` and on the right side place a checkmark in the box for `Developer`

Now go to the developer tab and on the left you'll see `Visual Basic` - click that

On the left of your Visual Basic window you will see your `VBAProject`, right click `insert - module` and paste the code below into the module

```
Function Kikio(Rng As String) As Variant
    Kikio= Evaluate(Rng)
End Function
```

Click `Debug - Compile VBAProject` and exit the visual basic window

Now on your sheet you can use the function `=Kikio()` to calculate a sum of one of those cells. Use this in conjunction with `=Sum()` to sum multiple `=Kikio()`s in this particular Workbook.

`=Sum(Kikio(A1), Kikio(A2))`

If you want the `=Kikio()` function available across all workbooks on the machine, you'll need to put it into your `PERSONAL.xlsb` file.

Comment: Function Kikio(Rng As String) As Variant // Kikio = Evaluate(Rng) // End Function

Comment: ah `string`. Thank you @SeanCheshire

Comment: Thanks a lot (your code need a typo correction after Evaluate. a `)`.)

Comment: Yeah, leftover from my prior (read: inferior) attempt at a solution

Answer (score 1):

I always prefer non-VBA solutions. There is an undocumented "Evaluate" function that you can use, but I wouldn't recommend using it for very large data sets. Here's how it works.

Under the `Formula` tab, Pick define name. Name it whatever you want (I used "Result"). And in the "Refers to", type in `=EVALUATE(Sheet1!A1)+EVALUATE(Sheet1!A2)`. you don't have to specify a sheet, but it will do that automatically for you after entering.

Now to use that result, just select a cell and type in "Result" and there you will find the result you want.

If you want to use bigger data sets, VBA might be needed, unless you don't mind the manuel work.

Comment: Thanks! but, is it possible to define 1 formula, and use it to calculate sum of different cells?
For example, "Result" gets cells list as input, and pass it to EVALUATE function. So `=Result(A1,A2)` means `=EVALUATE(Sheet1!A1)+EVALUATE(Sheet1!A2)` and `=Result(B1,B2)` means `=EVALUATE(Sheet1!B1)+EVALUATE(Sheet1!B2)`

Comment: As far as I know, you can't pass parameters along with a names field. Calling "result" is just calling a name, so I don't think that will work.

Comment: Btw, what I just noticed is that when you pull down results, and you haven't locked the cells (with "$"), the cells change in the formula you used when defining a name. So you might just want to drag your "results" cell to the right and that might calculate the B column too with having to make another formula.